# Second order polynomial regression vs linear regression. Lower PRESS statistic with insignificant second order coefficient

Tags: regression

I have dataset(50 observations):

```
head(cars)
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10
3     7    4
4     7   22
5     8   16
6     9   10
```

I want to build two models(second order polynomial and simple linear model) and compare their quality.

```
lm1 <- lm(cars$dist ~ cars$speed)
summary(lm1)
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -17.5791     6.7584  -2.601   0.0123 *  
cars$speed    3.9324     0.4155   9.464 1.49e-12 ***

lm2 <- lm(cars$dist ~ poly(cars$speed,2))
summary(lm2)
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            42.980      2.146  20.026  < 2e-16 ***
poly(cars$speed, 2)1  145.552     15.176   9.591 1.21e-12 ***
poly(cars$speed, 2)2   22.996     15.176   1.515    0.136
```

We see, that second order coefficient is not significant.

Then I have used PRESS statistic to compare the quality of prediction power:

```
df.lm1 <- fortify(lm1)
df.lm2 <- fortify(lm2)

PRESS.lm1 <- sum((df.lm1$.resid/(1 - df.lm1$.hat))^2)
PRESS.lm2 <- sum((df.lm2$.resid/(1 - df.lm2$.hat))^2)

> PRESS.lm1
[1] 12320.27
> PRESS.lm2
[1] 12151.46
```

And we see, that regardless of insignificant coefficient polynomial model predicts better. How can we explain it?

Comment: Just about anything can happen when you use three parameters to fit only six data values!  (I suspect you have a larger dataset than your question suggests.)

Comment: @whuber In my dataset i have 50 observations(cars dataset)

Comment: @whuber and of course model was built using all 50 observations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-sample PRESS will never increase from adding a variable (any variable, even random ones).

Predictive power should be assessed with some form of validation. Look around the site and you will find a lot of material on cross-validation, bootstrapping, etc.